# Upgraded to Xdebug 3 but still getting some old config variables

Tags: php, apache, xdebug, ubuntu-20.04, xdebug-3

I recently upgraded to Xdebug 3.0.1 on this server specs:

- Ubuntu Server 20.04
- PHP 7.3.24
- Xdebug 3.0.1

Xdebug is working fine, in the main config files I have this settings:

- /etc/php/7.3/cgi/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

> zend_extension=xdebug.so

- /etc/php/7.3/cgi/conf.d/21-xdebug-mgs.ini

> xdebug.mode = debug

Then in my website root folder in the .user.ini I have

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.client_host = "10.0.0.2"
xdebug.client_port = 9001
xdebug.discover_client_host = false
xdebug.log = '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/j39vm36/administrator/logs/xdebug.log'
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.output_dir = '/var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/j39vm36/administrator/logs/'
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

Despite having only those variables set, in phpinfo() I still get some old vars kicking up and getting Xdebug complain about it.
[image: Xdebug 3 with old variables]

Comment: So you're concerned about `phpinfo()` output only .. or perhaps PHP (well, Xdebug when you run any php script) complains about Xdebug stuff during run time (e.g. writes stuff into PHP standard error log or even std putput)? If it's about `phpinfo()` output only .. then please ignore it. AFAIK it will be there for some time so people can see it (esp those that got v3 without knowing it; to easy the upgrade a bit). If you want to see actual/pure Xdebug 3 config, please try `xdebug_info()` instead.

Comment: P.S. `xdebug.remote_connect_back = false` -- that's v2 value -- Xdebug will complain about that in PHP error log.

Comment: As I'm upgrading to v3 I don't know why phpinfo complains about those xdebug variables because I haven't set , so they may be set elsevere and I can't find where.

Comment: As I have said: 1) ignore those warnings in `phpinfo()`. 2) If you want to see actual/valid params only -- use `xdebug_info()` instead.